# preg_match_all subdomains under special conditions

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, subdomain

**Update:**

I'm using this regex:

`/[^a-z^-^0-9^@^%^\/^:^\.^-]((?<!w\.)(?!w+\.)([0-9a-z][0-9a-z\-]*\.){2,}[a-z]+)(["|\s|<]|$)/i`

The regex have a little problem when the string is only domains and nothing else, listed under each other in new lines

For example:

```
$string = 'sub84.example4.com
sub-example.example84.net
sub-84example.example-h1.org
www-example4124.domain.com
sub.example-www.com';
```

All domains should be matched, but he current regex is only match `sub-example.example84.net` and `www-example4124.domain.com`

I also looking to add some more conditions:

1) letters of domain must be small and can't be capital (the current one doesn't care about that)
EX: `Sub.example.Com` is not ok.

2) No `=SPACE` `(SPACE` `("` `:SPACE` before the domain and NO `SPACE)` or `SPACE=` `")` `SPACE:` after it.

EX:

```
$string = '

text = sub1.example.com text
text ( sub2.example.com text
text sub3.example.com = text
text sub4.example.com ) text
text ("sub5.example.com text
text sub6.example.com") text
text : sub7.example.com text
text sub8.example.com : text

';
```

None of them is ok

3) Exclude `.info` `.biz` `.tv` tlds

Thank you.

Comment: Provide your attempts at trying to solve this.

Comment: First use DOMDocument to extract href attributes and plain text parts. After and only after apply a pattern.

Comment: @hwnd It's bad (if not the worst), that's why i need help..but anyway, i put my codes to the question , thanks.

Comment: Ask a new question instead of reusing your old question.

Comment: @nhahtdh just don't want to ask a new question about the same thing, also this question has an open bounty and as you know, i can't get it back.

Comment: What is your real purpose? For example - you want to get all domains from a webpage, you have a tld zone file and want to parse all domain from there or ... (enter something here), because it could be a better for this than using expensive operations like matching text with regular expression?

Comment: @divaka I agree, I tried to divine what the intended behavior was from the examples and the regex but I'm a little uncertain that my answer got it right...

Comment: @user2203703 Just wanted to ping you here, I haven't seen a response from you and your bounty is winding down. (Hopefully you're aware that you have to click on the +50 under an answer's checkbox to award the bounty.) I think some clarification on [divaka](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1412896/divaka)'s question would be in order, since I'm sure you want a good answer after your edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand the purpose of doing this or the incredible number of conditions, but you might try this (rather really long one...):

```
(?<!http://)(?<!https://)(?<!www\.)(?![^\s<>]*[:@/])(?<![(=:] )(?<!\(")(?:(?<=[\s">])|^)(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.){2}(?!info|biz|tv)[a-z]+(?=[\s"<]|$)(?! [=):])(?!"\))
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/oW6tD0/1)

---

Breakdown:

```
(?<!http://)(?<!https://)(?<!www\.)        # Prevent http:// https:// and www.
(?![^\s<>]*[:@/])                          # Prevent : @ /
(?<![(=:] )(?<!\(")                        # Prevent '( ' '= ' etc
(?:(?<=[\s">])|^)                          # Ensure there's ' ', '>', '"' or beginning of line
(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.){2}(?!info|biz|tv)[a-z]+   # Main match, alphanumerics and -, 2 parts + tlds (excluding info, biz, tv
(?=[\s"<]|$)                               # Ensure there's ' ', '<', '"' or end of line
(?! [=):])(?!"\))                          # Prevent ' )' ' =' etc
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your regex is perfect for me, and you are right, no need for all these conditions, i will make it less, thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

Look-aheads and look-behinds are expensive as regexes go. You can do it without either with this monstrosity:

```
(?:^[^0-9a-zA-Z]??|[^=(:][^0-9a-zA-Z\-]|=[^ 0-9a-zA-Z]|\([^ "0-9a-zA-Z]|:[^ 0-9a-zA-Z]|[^0-9a-zA-Z]-)((?:[0-9a-z][0-9a-z\-]*\.){2,}(?:[ac-hj-su-z][a-z]*|b[a-z]?|bi[a-y]|b[a-z]{3,}|i[a-z]{0,2}|inf[a-np-z]|i[a-z]{4,}|t|t[a-uw-z]|t[a-z]{2,}))(?:[^a-zA-Z "]| [^=:)]|"[^)]|[ "]?$)
```

This will enforce lowercase sub-domains per *1*, properly remove all the pre and post-conditions you list in *2*, and disallow *.biz*, *.info*, and *.tv* per *3*.

But you'll need to use it with the `m` modifier so that `^` and `$` can match per line not just the beginning and end of the input. So you'd need to do something like:

```
preg_match_all('/(?:^[^0-9a-zA-Z]??|[^=(:][^0-9a-zA-Z\-]|=[^ 0-9a-zA-Z]|\([^ "0-9a-zA-Z]|:[^ 0-9a-zA-Z]|[^0-9a-zA-Z]-)((?:[0-9a-z][0-9a-z\-]*\.){2,}(?:[ac-hj-su-z][a-z]*|b[a-z]?|bi[a-y]|b[a-z]{3,}|i[a-z]{0,2}|inf[a-np-z]|i[a-z]{4,}|t|t[a-uw-z]|t[a-z]{2,}))(?:[^a-zA-Z "]| [^=:)]|"[^)]|[ "]?$)/m', $string, $foo);
```

Let me quickly explain the sections of the regex so this hopefully makes sense:

The first section is the alternative to a look behind at what was before the sub-domain it prevents the pre-conditions you listed in *2*: `(?:^[^0-9a-zA-Z]??|[^=(:][^0-9a-zA-Z\-]|=[^ 0-9a-zA-Z]|\([^ "0-9a-zA-Z]|:[^ 0-9a-zA-Z]|[^0-9a-zA-Z]-)` it is a non-capturing group which will match 1 of 6 options:

1. The start of a line and possibly 1 non-alpha-numeric character
2. A character other than `'='`, `'('`, or `':'` followed by a non-alpha-numeric non-`'-'` character
3. An `'='` followed by a non-space and non-alpha-numeric character
4. A `'('` followed by a character other than a `'"'`, space, or alpha-numeric
5. A `':'` followed by a non-space and non-alpha-numeric character
6. A non-alpha-numeric character followed by a `'-'` character

The second section which is inside the capture is your original sub-domain minus suffix match: `(?:[0-9a-z][0-9a-z\-]*\.){2,}`

The third section which is also inside the capture, eliminates sub-domains with the `"biz"`, `"info"`, or `"tv"` sufixes: `(?:[ac-hj-su-z][a-z]*|b[a-z]?|bi[a-y]|b[a-z]{3,}|i[a-z]{0,2}|inf[a-np-z]|i[a-z]{4,}|t|t[a-uw-z]|t[a-z]{2,})` it is a non-capturing group with 10 options:

1. A character other than `'b'`, `'i'`, or `'t'` followed by any number of lowercase characters
2. A `'b'` and some other lowercase character
3. `"bi"` followed by a non-`'z'` character
4. A `'b'` followed by 3 or more lowercase characters
5. An `'i'` followed by 2 or fewer lowercase characters
6. `"inf"` followed by a non-`'o'` character
7. An `'i'` followed by 4 or more lowercase characters
8. A `'t'` character
9. A `'t'` followed by a non-`'v'` character
10. A `'t'` followed by 2 or more lowercase characters

The final section prevents the post-conditions you listed in *2*: `(?:[^a-zA-Z "]| [^=:)]|"[^)]|[ "]?$)` it is a non-capturing group with 4 options:

1. A character that is not a space, `'"'`, lowercase, or uppercase character
2. A space followed by a character other than `'='`, `':'`, or `')'`
3. A `'"'` followed by a non-`')'` character
4. Non-space non-`'"'` followed by the end of line

Comment: +1 thank you very much, i really appreciate your help, the way you write regex is very advanced for me, i think i need a while to learn how to deal with regex like that.

Comment: @user2203703 Yup :) I don't know if it's as advanced as antiquated. C++11 implementations of `regex` still don't support look-ahead or look-behind, so you have to know the work around. The non-capturing group options work very well and in my opinion are more explicit on what they're searching for, but they come at a cost of much higher verbosity,  so on languages that support look-ahead and look-behind, don't feel like you're doing something wrong, it's just preference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the one

`/[^a-z^-^0-9^@^\/^:^\.^-]((?<!w\.)(?!w+\.)([0-9a-z][0-9a-z\-]*\.)+[a-z]+)(["\s<]|$)/ig`

Comment: This question has an open bounty worth +50 reputation, thank you.

Comment: What the heck is with all the `^`?

Comment: @HamZa: No, the regex in the question copied from this answer to add more requirement.